# Unable to pass token in header in Angular 4

Tags: angular, http-headers, bearer-token

I am calling api where I have to pass header with token but when I get response it show me `Unauthorised` but the same header  function I am using for calling other APi.

Here is my header function:

```
getAuthHeaderOption() {

    this.webToken = localStorage.getItem('web_token');// here token is available
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.webToken);
    let option = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return option;
}
```

And here Calling api :

getUserQuestionVideoList = function (userId, questionId) {

```
        return this.http.post(this.api_url + 'checkvideostatusonaskwazzer/'+userId+'/'+ questionId, this.getAuthHeaderOption()).map(res => res.json());
    }
```

This is network Tab
[image]
[image]

but I make the same request from postman then It is giving response, Post screen shot is below
[image]

what might be wrong here with my code  or server side issue.
Your help would be highly appropriated
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why don't you use a httpinterceptor?
https://itnext.io/angular-tutorial-implement-refresh-token-with-httpinterceptor-bfa27b966f57

Comment: Actually,  this header function is working for all api so still I am using it

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution of problemm my header was written in correct way.
I did  a little change in my function.

In my  code, I was  passing headers in place of request payload.

In GET method, second parameter is HeaderOptions

But in POST method, second parameter is request payload, Header Options is third 
parameter.

So  I pass an empty object as second parameter.

```
 getUserQuestionVideoList (questionId, userId) {
        return this.http.post(this.api_url + 'checkvideostatusonaskwazzer/'+userId+'/'+ 
        questionId, {},   this.getAuthHeaderOption()).map(res => res.json());

            }
```

and it Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

`import { HttpClient, HttpResponse ,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';`

```
getUserQuestionVideoList = function (userId, questionId) {
  let header = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.webToken);

  return this.http.post(this.api_url + 'checkvideostatusonaskwazzer/'+userId+'/'+ questionId, header ).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: `let header = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.webToken);`
here header is showing`undefined`

Comment: like this `let header = new Headers().set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.webToken);`

Comment: ` import { HttpClient, HttpResponse ,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: I have imported this one already `import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, ResponseContentType, Response } from '@angular/http';`

Comment: I Imported but still showing unauthorised, but working this request on post, really can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Create HttpInterceptor

```
@Injectable()
    export class ApiTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            // add authorization header with basic auth credentials if available
            let auth = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('auth'));
            if (auth) {
                if(auth.token) {
                    // console.log(request,"requseet");
                    request = request.clone({
                        setHeaders: {
                            Authorization: `bearer ${auth.token}`
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            return next.handle(request);
        }
    }
```

this http interceptor will send token in each request

Write In AppModule Provider

```
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: NoopInterceptor, multi: true }
```

you can get example here : https://stackblitz.com/angular/kmeqdgdrenj

Comment: it is ok but my header function is working for all api  only issue with this api

Comment: yes, this http interceptor will send automatically in each request in header, so no need set header in each request.